# Disable mouse cursor inactivity hide

Tags: android, android-source

The default behavior when using an external mouse with Android is to hide the cursor/mouse pointer after ~15 seconds.

How can I disable this functionality, so the cursor is shown at all times?

I'm building from AOSP source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The file to look in is:

```
frameworks/base/services/input/PointerController.cpp
```

[The file on AndroidXRef](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/input/PointerController.cpp)

The inactivity timeout is defined on line 39 (Android 4.2.2):

```
static const nsecs_t INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT_DELAY_TIME_NORMAL = 15 * 1000 * 1000000LL; // 15 seconds
```

The method used for fading the cursor:

```
void PointerController::fade(Transition transition) {
    AutoMutex _l(mLock);

    // Remove the inactivity timeout, since we are fading now.
    removeInactivityTimeoutLocked();

    // Start fading.
    if (transition == TRANSITION_IMMEDIATE) {
        mLocked.pointerFadeDirection = 0;
        mLocked.pointerAlpha = 0.0f;
        updatePointerLocked();
    } else {
        mLocked.pointerFadeDirection = -1;
        startAnimationLocked();
    }
}
```

Commented out everything in the method except:

```
removeInactivityTimeoutLocked();
```

Since there's no point in having the inactivity timeout running in the background, when it isn't used.